# RangeError: Invalid status code: 0

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, webstorm

I am having an issue where I am getting the following error code when attempting a POST request on this application (bearing in mind I am a beginner node.js/js programmer):

Error:

```
[20:22:28] [nodemon] starting `node app.js`
Running server on 3000
Mon, 27 Jun 2016 19:22:31 GMT express deprecated res.send(status, body): Use res.status(status).send(body) instead at routes\edit.js:35:25
c:\Users\Matt\WebstormProjects\ghs_restart\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:98
    process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
                                  ^

RangeError: Invalid status code: 0
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (_http_server.js:192:11)
    at ServerResponse._implicitHeader (_http_server.js:157:8)
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.end (_http_outgoing.js:573:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (c:\Users\Matt\WebstormProjects\ghs_restart\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:204:10)
    at ServerResponse.json (c:\Users\Matt\WebstormProjects\ghs_restart\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:249:15)
    at ServerResponse.send (c:\Users\Matt\WebstormProjects\ghs_restart\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:151:21)
    at c:\Users\Matt\WebstormProjects\ghs_restart\routes\edit.js:35:25
    at c:\Users\Matt\WebstormProjects\ghs_restart\node_modules\mongodb\lib\collection.js:416:18
    at handleCallback (c:\Users\Matt\WebstormProjects\ghs_restart\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:96:12)
    at c:\Users\Matt\WebstormProjects\ghs_restart\node_modules\mongodb\lib\collection.js:705:5
```

app.js:

```
var express = require('express');

var router = express.Router();

var app = express();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use( bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
    extended: true
}));

var path = require('path');

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

var index = require('./routes/index');
var edit = require('./routes/edit');

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/edit', edit);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.set('views', 'views');

app.listen(port, function (err) {
    console.log("Running server on", port);
});

module.exports = index;
```

The following is my edit.js route, where I believe the issue is occurring:

```
var express = require('express');

var router = express.Router();

var app = express();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use( bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
    extended: true
}));

var path = require('path');

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

var index = require('./routes/index');
var edit = require('./routes/edit');

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/edit', edit);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.set('views', 'views');

app.listen(port, function (err) {
    console.log("Running server on", port);
});

module.exports = index;
```

Comment: I assume this is an error within a callback, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Can you update your question with the good code sample for `edit.js` ? Seems like you pasted `app.js` in it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I had a similar error message just now and managed to solve the problem by changing:

```
res.status(statusCode);
```

to:

```
if (statusCode >= 100 && statusCode < 600)
  res.status(statusCode);
else
  res.status(500);
```

or just:

```
res.status(statusCode >= 100 && statusCode < 600 ? err.code : 500);
```

I.e. make sure you aren't trying to set an [invalid HTTP status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) somewhere.

It's likely this is the issue but it looks like you've accidentally duplicated the `app.js` code instead of pasting the `edit.js` code in the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Saved me a lot of time :-)

Comment: When used statusCode, it threw ReferenceError

Comment: @DivyaGalla statusCode must be defined first. I.e. `var statusCode = 200;` Use whatever code is suitable for your situation.

Answer (score 3):

This case also happen when we have validation error on form save and we are using res.redirect instead of res.render method

for example-

Please Use

```
res.render('users/add', {
    countries: countries
});
```

instead of (it's wrong statement for node)

```
res.redirect('/users/add', {
    countries: countries
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem which I solved by using:

```
res.send('0')
```

instead of

```
res.send(0)
```

Comment: Yup! that's it! `res.send(String(result))`

Answer (score 0):

for me the issue was that i had not created my upload directory and it returns me the error. may be you should consider to create your `./upload` directory first, because of permission issues on linux.