# Express Invalid Status Code0

Tags: node.js, express

So basically, I am doing this:

```
app.get("/moderation_enabled", (req, res) => {
    var id = req.param("id");

    con.query(`SELECT moderation FROM server_settings WHERE id=${id}`, (err, result) => {
        if (err) { 
          return res.send(`error ${err}`);
        }
        if (result[0].moderation == undefined){
          return res.send("server not found");
        } else{
          return res.send(result[0].moderation);
        }
    });
})
```

but, when I run it, when I get an invalid id, then it says server not found, but when it does find it, it gives this error:

[image: Here is my error:]

thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RangeError: Invalid status code: 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38061781/rangeerror-invalid-status-code-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the value of `result[0].moderation` is just a Number 0, and `res.send()` sees it as a status code, then you get the error.
Convert `result[0].moderation` to a string can solve your problem.

```
 return res.send(`${result[0].moderation}`);
```

Comment: I mean, it would by return res.send(`${result[0].moderation}`);, but thx!